# Playhaven iOS SDK: Show only Casino game not works

Tags: ios, playhaven

I got one requirement to use Playhaven iOS ads sdk. I used below code and set ads filter to casino games only. But its not working.

Here is my Code:

```
-(void) PlayHavenMoreGames
{
    PHPublisherContentRequest *request = [PHPublisherContentRequest requestForApp:PLAYHAVEN_TOKEN secret:PLAYHAVEN_SECRET placement:PLACEMENT delegate:self];
    [request send];
}
```

Anything else missing to call ?

Here is code: https://app.box.com/s/t212o8axqc75fzqiz3dm

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the issue is in your code.
You should email support@playhaven.com with this question. They are pretty responsive usually.

Good luck!

Comment: Got reply from playhaven...One problem with code is I for got to call PHPublisherOpenRequest...and after adding also not worked...!!! Its ok let me remove this feature from game :)